# SQL Server stored procedure return table with count of uniques per user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have found a little here and a little there but nothing that really covers the question that I have so here goes. I have ordered a book from amazon but it won't be here for another week and I really need to this ASAP

I have two tables which contain basically the following.

`Table A` has the users id number, login name, wins, losses, ties

`Table B` has the User id number, when the game ended, game state

What I want is to create a stored procedure that will return the top 10 for wins for the last week.

```
Loginname | total wins, last 7 days | all wins | all losses | all ties
Name1     |         10              |   40     |     8      |      6
Name2     |          9              |   96     |    76      |      19
```

etc....

What I have so far is:

```
SELECT A.login,
       A.draws_count,
       A.losses_count,
       A.wins_count
FROM   [TableB] AS B
       INNER JOIN
       [TableA] AS A
       ON B.won_by_id = A.id
WHERE  B.win_defined_time > (GETDATE() - 7)
       AND B.state = 'OVER';
```

From there I have no clue how to return the table that I need. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. (also keep in mind that the 'total wins for the last 7 days' field does not exist in either table.)

Comment: The fields used in your query do not match up with the fields you say are defined for tableA and tableB. Could you post the actual sql to create the tables? (In Sql Management Studio right click on the table name in the object explorer then 'Script Table As -> Create To -> New Query Editor Windows' then copy and past the `CREATE TABLE` statement into your question.)

Comment: There is a difference between your subject line and the content of your question.  For a count of uniques per user, you could do select user_id, count(distinct something) etc.  Getting the top 10 wins for last week is a different query altogether and the way to do it depends on the type of database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a schema and sample data such as the following:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Competitors]
(
    [id]         INT          NOT NULL,
    [login_name] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [wins]       INT          NOT NULL,
    [losses]     INT          NOT NULL,
    [ties]       INT          NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Events]
(
    [id]            INT          NOT NULL,
    [Competitorid]  VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [EventDateTime] DATETIME     NOT NULL,
    [winner]        BIT          NOT NULL,
    [EventStatus]   VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT  INTO Competitors (id, login_name, wins, losses, ties)
VALUES                  (1, 'Player 1', 40, 8, 6),
                        (2, 'Player 2', 96, 76, 19),
                        (3, 'Player 3', 1, 0, 0)

INSERT  INTO Events (id, Competitorid, EventDateTime, winner, EventStatus)
VALUES             (1, 1, '2013-01-25 01:05:25.000', 1, 'OVER'),
                   (2, 1, '2013-01-26 01:05:25.000', 1, 'OVER'),
                   (3, 1, '2013-01-27 14:05:25.000', 1, 'OVER'),
                   (4, 1, '2013-01-28 01:05:25.000', 1, 'OVER'),
                   (5, 1, '2013-01-29 15:05:25.000', 1, 'OVER'),
                   (6, 1, '2013-01-30 01:05:25.000', 1, 'OVER'),
                   (7, 1, '2013-01-31 22:05:25.000', 1, 'OVER'),
                   (8, 1, '2013-02-01 01:05:25.000', 1, 'OVER'),
                   (9, 1, '2013-02-02 21:05:25.000', 1, 'OVER'),
                   (10, 1, '2013-01-02 11:05:25.000', 0, 'INPROGRESS'),
                   (11, 1, '2013-01-30 01:05:25.000', 1, 'OVER'),
                   (12, 2, '2013-01-25 11:05:25.000', 1, 'OVER'),
                   (13, 2, '2013-01-26 01:05:25.000', 1, 'OVER'),
                   (14, 2, '2013-01-27 11:25:25.000', 1, 'OVER'),
                   (15, 2, '2013-01-28 01:05:25.000', 1, 'OVER'),
                   (16, 2, '2013-01-29 11:45:25.000', 1, 'OVER'),
                   (17, 2, '2013-01-30 01:45:25.000', 1, 'OVER'),
                   (18, 2, '2013-01-31 12:15:25.000', 1, 'OVER'),
                   (19, 2, '2013-02-01 01:05:25.000', 1, 'OVER'),
                   (20, 2, '2013-02-02 22:25:25.000', 1, 'OVER'),
                   (21, 2, '2013-02-02 15:05:25.000', 0, 'INPROGRESS'),
                   (22, 2, '2013-01-25 01:05:25.000', 1, 'OVER'),
                   (23, 1, '2013-01-30 01:05:25.000', 0, 'OVER'),
                   (24, 2, '2013-01-30 01:05:25.000', 0, 'OVER'),
                   (25, 3, '2012-01-30 01:05:25.000', 1, 'OVER')
```

You can return the names and wins data for the ten people with the most wins in the last 7 days using the following query:

```
SELECT TOP 10 login_name,
              recent_wins,
              wins AS 'All Wins',
              losses AS 'All losses',
              ties AS 'All Ties'
FROM   Competitors
       INNER JOIN
       (SELECT   COUNT(*) AS recent_wins,
                 Competitorid
        FROM     events
        WHERE    winner = 1
                 AND eventdatetime BETWEEN GetDate() - 7 AND GetDate()
                 AND EventStatus = 'OVER'
        GROUP BY Competitorid) AS recent_event_winners
                 ON Competitors.ID = recent_event_winners.Competitorid;
ORDER BY recent_wins DESC
```

This query works by joining the data in the Competitors table together with a subquery on the data in the events table that is calaculating the number of recent wins and then taking the top 10 results. For users with a win in the last seven days, the subquery returns the count of the number of wins the user has had for events that are over during that time period.

**Note:** users without any wins during the time period will not be returned by either query so the results may have fewer than 10 results.

A SQL Fiddle with the above sql creation scripts and query can be found at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0ebc8/2